# Bootstrap Tabs for Joomla module (modChrome)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'd like to create a module position with a Bootstrap Tab Style.

The Markup for Bootstrap should be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

My modChrome is something like that:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php  
    foreach($modules as $rendermodule) { 
        echo '<li><a href="#'.$rendermodule->title.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$rendermodule->title.'&nbsp;'.$modulecount.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
>
```

What I know need is a way to add a class="active" to the first `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop rather than the foreach:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < $modulecount; $i++) {
        $rendermodule = $modules[i]; 
        echo '<li';
        if($i==0): echo ' class="active"';
        echo '><a href="#'.$rendermodule->title.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$rendermodule->title.'&nbsp;'.$modulecount.'</a></li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

or use a variable that gets cleared after the first loop:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php  
    $active = ' class="active"';
    foreach($modules as $rendermodule) { 
        echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="#'.$rendermodule->title.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$rendermodule->title.'&nbsp;'.$modulecount.'</a></li>';
        $active = '';
    }
?>
</ul>
```